# Using an input field as a jquery selector

Tags: jquery, variables

I'm creating a Search page in a smartphone app and the search should search the app for a match. When I hard code a search term the jquery selector works fine, when I replace the hard-coded selector with a variable it returns "undefined". I must be missing something blindingly obvious but I just don't see it after several hours.

Below is the search page with the input field

```
<input name="searchTxt" type="text" maxlength="32" id="searchTxt" class="searchField"/>
<button onclick="searchApp()"> Search </button>
<p id="searchResultsP">Search results go here</p>
```

Here is the js that should search the app and overwrite the "searchResultsP" paragraph above with the search results. I added a few Alerts to try and figure out where it's failing and added comments below to show the results.

```
function searchApp() {
    var $searchTerm = "";
$searchTerm =  document.getElementById("searchTxt").value;
alert ("$searchTerm is " + $searchTerm); // this works correctly
alert("search 1 results " + $( ".english:contains($searchTerm)" ).html());// returns undefined
alert("search 2 results hard coded " + $( ".english:contains('arrest')" ).html()); // this works correctly
var $searchResultsAlert = $( ".english:contains('arrest')" ).html();
alert ("search 3 results hard coded are " + $searchResultsAlert);// this works correctly

// Now overwrite the searchresultsP
    document.getElementById("searchResultsP").innerHTML = $( ".english:contains('arrest')" ).value; // this returns undefined
```

Comment: oops the last two lines above should be in the js function..sorry

Comment: There's an "edit" link right below the post.

Comment: Since you are using jQuery at the last.. use this..`document.getElementById("searchResultsP").innerHTML = $( ".english:contains('arrest')" ).val();`

Comment: Maybe a http://jsfiddle.net/ of what you are trying to do might help!

Comment: Try `$( ".english:contains(" + $searchTerm + ")" )` , note quotation marks. Can post `html` including element having class `english` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The expression

```
 alert("search 1 results " + $( ".english:contains($searchTerm)" ).html());
```

is searching for "$searchTerm" literally but not for the variable value `$searchTerm`.

change to

```
 alert("search 1 results " + $( ".english:contains(" + $searchTerm + ")" ).html());
```

Comment: Thanks @Axel for the suggestions, I tried yours and the one from Sandeep and it didn't fix the problem. I had previously tried to set up a jsfiddle but unfortunately the Alert statements did not work at all - I have no idea why. So, I set up another jsfiddle without the alerts and it returns a value of :undefined. Here's a link to the new jsfiddle < http://jsfiddle.net/tonybabb/Lvws4s0u/12/ > . Thanks again for any assistance you can provide.Tony

Comment: In your jsfiddle, the property of an input field is "`value`" and not "val": Updated the jsfiddle, works like a charm.

Comment: Thank you @Axel, that fixed it. When I split the statement that I thought was causing the problem I also changed "val" to "value" which is why I thought I had fixed the problem. Thank you again, your help was very much appreciated. Tony

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I figured it out. Not exactly sure why but the statement :

```
document.getElementById("searchResultsP").innerHTML = $( ".english:contains(" + $searchTerm + ")" ).html();
```

was inserting a bunch of js code in the paragraph. The resolution was to do it in two steps, first get the search results in a variable and then insert the variable in the paragraph as shown below

```
var $searchResultsAlert = $( ".english:contains(" + $searchTerm + ")" ).html();
document.getElementById("searchResultsP").innerHTML = $searchResultsAlert
```

Thanks again for your time.